# How to traverse the DOM elements of a JQuery object in IE7?

Tags: jquery, xml, internet-explorer, object

I have an xml response from an API request stored in a JQuery object (called $xml). To get to the bit of information I need, I was using: `$xml[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].textContent`. This works on Chrome, Firefox, and IE10+, but IE=<9 does not represent the object the same way.

Code that works in Chrome, Firefox, and IE10+:

```
$(function() {
  $.get('proxy.php', function(data) {
    if (typeof data == 'string') {
      console.error(data);
    } else {
      var test = $.parseXML(data);
      var $xml = $(data);
      console.log(data);

      alert($xml[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].textContent);
    }
  });
});
```

In the debugger in IE it shows the [0] index of the object's array – but where other browsers then show descendants like 'children' and 'childNodes' – lower IE just shows `0: [object]`, with no option to expand and see inside of said `[object]`.

---

**How can I traverse the contents of my JQuery object in a way that works in IE7+ as well as Chrome and Firefox?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found another method to achieve this that is more cross-browser compatible and easier to read.

```
$(function() {
 $.get('proxy.php', function(data) {
  if (typeof data == 'string') {
    console.error(data);
  } else {
    var test = $.parseXML(data);
    var $xml = $(data);
    console.log(data);

    alert($xml.find("Description").text());
  }
 });
});
```

Using `.find()` with the NodeNames of the xml fields allows for more flexible traversing of the response. `.html()` works okay with Chrome and Firefox (and maybe Edge), but older IE needed `.text()` to return desired information.

This worked for me and I'm able to *if..else* with the value of "Description" or any other parameter of the xml response that I'm looking to attach functionality to.